# Can the blender game engine render diffuse material nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, game-engine, node-editor, shaders

I have a plane with a diffuse material of a blue color, a cube of a red color. I can see them perfectly well using cycles. When I use the game engine render all I get is gray no colors. Can the blender game engine render diffuse material nodes?

Is there a node that says render node to game engine renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blender game engine **cannot** render cycles materials. [This](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/23/physically-based-rendering-in-the-blender-game-engine/) might bring similar results, It's not currently available for download at the time of writing.

Comment: I've found a script to convert Blender internal materials to Cycles. It was unclear if it would also convert Cycles materials to Blender internal.