# Why does glass material not show in Blenders game engine when it is running?

Tags: materials, game-engine

Why does glass material not show in Blenders game engine when it is running? I have recently been trying to create glass objects like windows for my game but when I run my game the glass material shows up black. I have done research and have found nothing but other things that has no to do with the answer I am looking for. So i figure coming here to ask my question is my last resort. So is there anyway to make glass material show up when blenders game engine is running?

Comment: Cycles materials and effects like reflection, refraction, volumetric, etc. in BI materials are not supported in the GE. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2741/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14655/599

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvfvCURIcT4&hd=1

Comment: I tried to reproduce your result, first a material with z-transparency worked fine after switching back and forth from multitexture to GLSL it stopped to be transparent. I couldn't find out why this happens.

Comment: One of Andrew Price's recent tutorials addressed this by baking the textures in cycles. Here is a link. http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/

Comment: Yes, I did use z-transparency. I tried to use GLSL and multitexture as suggested from a source but it just made the game white. And even when i change the colors the game ends up white. Does the Game Engine not support glass materials?

Comment: Make sure that the glass object is its own object without any additional materials. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First be warned the BGE is currently extremely buggy. Some settings lead to unreproducible effects. Sometimes GLSL renders everything white in the internal player but the external still works (Reloading the .blend or restarting Blender fixes this). Everytime I try to reproduce it with a saved file it doesn't happen (so I can't file a bug-report).

Setup of transparent material:

[image]

For other materials of faces that become visible through the transparency of the windows disable *Backface Culling* otherwise the faces wouldn't be rendered because Blender would assume that the faces aren't visible.

A simple scene with left window without faces and right window with z-tranparency material.

Shading Mode set to Multitexture:

[image]

Shading Mode set to GLSL

[image]

You find the *Shading  Mode* in the *3D Viewport's* properties panel:

[image]

[Demo .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/31162)

Comment: But one more question. I recently got the blendertool kit to import makehuman models. I don't where to put it. It will be an add-on so I ended finding the add-ons folder in blender. Should I place it in blenders add-ons folder?

Comment: You could just enable the MHX-importer addon from the user-preferences. An updated version not yet packed with the Blender distribution should be installed in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons (if you use windows).